# Tell if Android P phone is using gestures or navigation bar

Tags: android, gesture, navigationbar

How can my app determine if a user who is on Android 9 (P) is using the classic navigation bar or the new, iOS-like gestures?

Answer (score 0):

```
view.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
            @Override
            public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsets insets) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onApplyWindowInsets: B"+ insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom());
                return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
            }
        });
```

I declared it inside onViewCreated method in a fragment. the insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom() returned different values when navigation mode was changed.

reference: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/gesturalnav

Comment: Where is the solution here? How can anyone check if it's gesture navigation or not? And why do you need a View for this? Can't check without a View?